# Why is pip not updating tensorflow correctly, and, if it is, why is the 'attrib error' still thrown?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, artificial-intelligence

I've installed tensorflow over pip3 and python3, and am working on it. While using the colum function, the commonly experienced error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column'`.

It might look like a duplicate question, but I've looked at the other occurrences of the same question, but, after updating the file (`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`), I checked the version. The version 0.12.0 is shown. So why does pip still show its completely new. Is 0.12.0 the newest version?

When I attempted to uninstall tensorflow and re-install it, it refuses to re-install. I'm using `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`. The error thrown here is `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is your pip updated? Also, try uninstalling tensorflow completely and doing a fresh install instead of `--upgrade`. Perhaps some dependencies didn't get updated properly

Comment: The error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow` is being shown now

Comment: 0.12.0 is way too old. What do following commands return: `python3 -V`, `pip3 -V`, `python3 -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_platform())"` and `python3 -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"`

Comment: Here's what I got: Python version: `3.7.0`, pip version `18.0`, `macosx_10_13_x86_64`, and `cp37m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the most probable solution to the attribute error is the update problem. However, if you're encountering the `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`, the easiest solution is to use following code.

`pip install --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-py2-none-any.whl` (for python 2)

or

`pip install --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl` (for python 3)